# Android: EXTRA_TEXT in putExtra method of ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share a string on facebook by ACTION_SEND intent.
This is my code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    String linktext = linkTV.getText().toString();

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, linktext);
```

String of linktext have multiple lines, for example:

```
Một cô gái trẻ bước vào cửa hàng thực phẩm nói với người bán hàng:

- Bác bán cho tôi tất cả cà chua, trứng thối của cửa hàng.

- Có ngay, thưa cô. Nhưng cô mua nhiều như vậy để làm gì?

- Để chuẩn bị cho buổi biểu diễn ca nhạc tối nay.

- Làm như thế liệu có hơi ác với ca sĩ đó không?

- Không, tôi chính là cô ca sĩ ấy. Cẩn thận vẫn hơn bác ạ!
```

but it is not appeared when I share in Facebook.
I don't know why?
I tried which several multiple line strings but the result is the same.
Any help? thanks.

Comment: Could you be able to post the same content to twitter, whatsapp etc. with the same code?

Comment: You can't set the EXTRA_TEXT because Facebook does not allow your app to preset the message for the user, the user must type it themselves.

Comment: Thanks! So, how can I share an item on Facebook? I have a listView, each have a textView and a button, when click on the button, the content of textView is shared on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this it will work,

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

Here need to support appropriate text fonts.then only you can get the text

Comment: need to support your fonts

Comment: The Facebook application does not handle either the EXTRA_SUBJECT or EXTRA_TEXT fields. Please check this link: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/332619626816423/